# Is 61cm (24 inch) folded length too much for a tripod?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

Do you consider this length to be too much when plied(closed) for a tripod? The weight is 1.95kg (4.3 pounds). Do you consider this would be inconvenient to use in the city?

Comment: Plied? Never heard that in use before. Merriam-webster doesn't show that it means "closed" either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If they make it, it is probably convenient to someone.**

You have to look at all the specs and decide which is good for you. Personally, I think this would be too big for travel as you would need a large suitcase just because you have such a big tripod. If you are not traveling with it, or doing so by car, it can do though.

Consider though that 61cm folded means at the very least 71cm length when you include a head. Add a leveling base or a fancier head and it gets really long.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've found the Manfrotto 190XPROB at 22.4 inches is the largest possible tripod to take in carryon - and even then you have to either squeeze it in diagonally or carry it on in a duffle bag.  If you were planning to fly with a tripod at all you should not get a larger tripod.  The head height is not as important as you can easily unscrew the head for travel (and should so you can pad it better anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Not really, higher grade tripods are usually bigger and sturdier than the cheap ones since that helps to reduce vibration. If you're getting a tripod, spend a little time on the research front and look at options that can balance quality with your budget, but avoid the cheapest options like the plague, they will not help you and will waste your money.

Now, if you want something light, easy to use, and not so bulky, you might want to consider a decent monopod. While you can't just let it go, it will help stability and is often allowed in places that don't allow tripods.